# Vue: Ignore property until axios then

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm using axios for API calls and everything works, but I have to specify blank values for mustache properties first.

`{{page_data.title}}`

will give an error, even though axios WILL be populating the value.

I can overcome this by first setting:

`page_date.title: ''`

BUT this becomes complicated, and counterproductive, with array data.

What would be the solution for this?

Comment: can you show axios request code using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [conditional ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to check if the key is in the object first and only if it is, use it's value, e.g.:

```
{{'title' in page_data ? page_data.title : '' }}
```

Otherwise, you could use Lodash's [`_.get` method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get), e.g.:

```
{{ _.get(page_data, 'title', '') }}
```

`_.get` is also useful for when you want to get a "deep" property, e.g.:

```
{{ _.get(page_data, 'article.title', '') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "v-if" before you render  {{page_data.title}} E.g

```
<p v-if="page_data.title"> {{page_data.title}} </p>
```